# Does the order of deletes with foreign keys matter when inside a stored procedure BEGIN END block

Tags: sql-server

I have a stored procedure in SQL Server 2012 database. I am deleting from a PARENT table and then deleting the CHILD table rows.  The CHILD table has a foreign key that points to the primary key in the parent table.

Does the order of my deletes matter if it is all inside a BEGIN END block? Must I have delete the CHILD rows before the PARENT row ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although some database systems support deferrable constraints, in SQL Server all constraints must be satisfied at the end of each individual statement. And so, unless the foreign keys have an [`ON DELETE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188066.aspx) specification that allows the delete to proceed, you'll not be able to delete parent rows until no child rows reference them.

It should also be noted, though, that [`BEGIN`...`END`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms190487.aspx) have no impact here. They are merely a means of grouping several statements together. Even in database systems that support deferrable constraints, the deferral is dealt with in terms of the *transaction*. Transactions are started and finished with `BEGIN TRANSACTION` and `COMMIT [TRANSACTION]` (or `ROLLBACK`), not `BEGIN`...`END`.